# java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

Tags: java, xml, maven, jpa

I am using jdk 13 but I want to create entity and write to database its.

and I added project->run configurations->arguments->VM Arguments
--add-modules java.xml.bind 
then I ran the project but , I am getting this error :

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found
```

I dont know, I am getting error why.I suppose my jdk is problem.But I dont know exactly.what should I do?

Test.java

```
package com.kerem.blog;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setDataName("Kerem");
        data.setDataValue(23.2);
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(data);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        manager.close();
    }

}
```

Data.java

```
package com.kerem.blog;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class Data {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long dataId;
    private String dataName;
    private double dataValue;
    public long getDataId() {
        return dataId;
    }
    public void setDataId(long dataId) {
        this.dataId = dataId;
    }
    public String getDataName() {
        return dataName;
    }
    public void setDataName(String dataName) {
        this.dataName = dataName;
    }
    public double getDataValue() {
        return dataValue;
    }
    public void setDataValue(double dataValue) {
        this.dataValue = dataValue;
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Turkey" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                value="kerem2112" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="create" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.keremsarmis</groupId>
  <artifactId>blogbasic</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: add `<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency> `
to your dependencies in pom